# Can I Return and trigger an action e.g. increment a counter with .WillRepeatedly?

Tags: c++, mocking, googlemock

I would like to trigger an action **AND** `Return` something on `.WillRepeatedly()` in `googlemock`.

Does anyone know how to do it? (Is writing a function that will increment a referenced parameter and return what I want is the only option here?)

This are my failed attempts to do so:

```
EXPECT_CALL(parser, getTemplateFileName(_))
  .WillRepeatedly(Invoke(parser.counter++), Return(TEMPLATE_NAME));
```

---

```
class TemplateParser: public Parser
{
    public:
        MOCK_METHOD1(getTemplateFileName, std::string(const string& name));

        void incrementCounter()
        {
          ++counter;
        }
};

// ...

EXPECT_CALL(parser, getTemplateFileName(_))
  .WillRepeatedly(Invoke(&parser, &TemplateParser::incrementCounter),
                  Return(TEMPLATE_NAME));
```

**EDIT**:

So as [kerrek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb) mentioned I have tried this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(parser, getTemplateFileName(_))
  .WillRepeatedly(DoAll(
                  Invoke(&parser, &TemplateParser::incrementCounter),
                  Return(TEMPLATE_NAME)
                       )
                  );
```

But I am getting errors like:

```
/opt/gmock-1.7.0/include/gmock/gmock-more-actions.h:80:   instantiated from ‘Result testing::internal::InvokeMethodAction<Class, MethodPtr>::Perform(const ArgumentTuple&) const [with Result = void, ArgumentTuple = std::tuple<const std::string&>, Class = TemplateParser, MethodPtr = unsigned int (TemplateParser::*)()]’
/opt/gmock-1.7.0/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:371:   instantiated from ‘typename testing::internal::Function<F>::Result testing::PolymorphicAction<Impl>::MonomorphicImpl<F>::Perform(const typename testing::internal::Function<F>::ArgumentTuple&) [with F = void(const std::string&), Impl = testing::internal::InvokeMethodAction<TemplateParser, unsigned int (TemplateParser::*)()>]’
test/src/ParserTest.cpp:315:   instantiated from here
/opt/gmock-1.7.0/include/gmock/gmock-generated-actions.h:83: error: too many arguments to function
/opt/gmock-1.7.0/include/gmock/gmock-generated-actions.h:83: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void'
make: *** [test/obj/ParserTest.o] Error 1
```

Comment: `WillRepeatedly(DoAll(...))`?

Comment: I thought that would help but please check my edit

Comment: Ah, wait, `Invoke` can only be used to delegate to some other function of the same type. It's not the same as just "calling any code". Maybe make a custom function of the correct type that increments the counter and then calls the mock? `std::string myFn(const string& name) { ++counter; return getTemplateFileName(name); }`? Then just `WillRepeatedly(Invoke(..., ...::myFn))`.

Comment: Use `InvokeWithoutArgs` - check in gmock doc - I am not sure the name is exactly correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DoAll` as Kerrek suggests in comments using `InvokeWithoutArgs`.

Another alternative is to create a custom function to perform both actions in a very straightforward way by using a lambda.

```
EXPECT_CALL(parser, getTemplateFileName(_))
    .WillRepeatedly(InvokeWithoutArgs([&]()
                                      {
                                          parser.counter++;
                                          return TEMPLATE_NAME;
                                      });
```